# Rails: retrieving model id from database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to retrieve the id of the model named "gnib" and submit it in a form in a hidden field so as to allow a user to effectively repost the "gnib" when they click a submit button attached to each gnib. However when I click the button I get the error:

```
ActiveRecord::Recordnotfound in Sharescontroller#create
Couldn't find Gnib with id=
```

I would really appreciate it if someone could help me solve this problem.

**Gnib model**

```
attr_accessible :title, :image, :content 
mount_uploader :image, ImagesUploader
belongs_to :user
validates :content, presence: true, length: { maximum: 80 }  
validates :user_id, presence: true
default_scope order: 'gnibs.created_at DESC'
has_many :reverse_shares, foreign_key: "regnib_id", class_name: "Share", dependent:     :destroy
has_many :regnibbers, through: :reverse_shares
```

In my user model I have:

**User model**

```
 has_many :gnibs, dependent: :destroy
 has_many :shares, foreign_key: "regnibber_id", dependent: :destroy
 has_many :regnibs, through: :shares
```

I used a join model named "Share" to facilitate the repost or "regnib" functionality.

**Share model**

```
attr_accessible :regnib_id
belongs_to :regnibber, class_name: "User"
belongs_to :regnib, class_name: "Gnib"
validates :regnibber_id, presence: true
validates :regnib_id, presence: true
```

In the **share controller** I have:

```
 def create
 @gnib = Gnib.find(params[:share][:regnib_id])
 current_user.regnib!(@gnib)
 redirect_to @gnib
 end
```

In the **gnib controller** I have:

```
 def create
 @gnib = current_user.gnibs.build(params[:gnib])
 end
```

In the **user controller** under the show function I have:

```
 @gnib = current_user.gnibs.build(params[:gnib]) if signed_in?
```

The **partial** for rendering the **gnibs** is in the user show page and is as follows:

```
<li>
 <span class="Title"><%= gnib.title %></span>
 <span class="Image"><%= image_tag gnib.image_url(:thumb) %></span>
 <span class="content"><%= gnib.content %></span>
 <span class="timestamp">
 Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(gnib.created_at) %> ago.
 </span>
 <%= render 'regnib_form' %>
</li>
```

While the **partial** for the **regnib** form is:

```
<% unless current_user?(@user) %>
<div id="regnib_form">
<% if current_user.regnibbing?(@gnib) %>
<% else %>
<%= form_for(current_user.shares.build(regnib_id: @gnib.id)) do |f| %>
<div><%= f.hidden_field :regnib_id %></div>
<%= f.submit "Regnib", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
<h4> Regnibs <%= @gnib.regnibbers.count %></h4>
<% end %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
  <%= f.hidden_field :regnib_id %>
</div>
```

should be:

```
<div>
  <%= f.hidden_field :regnib_id , :value=> @gnib.id %>
</div>
```